# Kubernetes Pods not available after Fedora (Single Node) installation

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have started with Kubernetes lately and got some experiences with using Minikube and of course kubectl. Now I wanted to setup my own cluster and I have followed this official description: 
[Fedora (Single Node) Installation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config/)

Master and node can connect and the node status is 'ready':

```
[root@fed-master ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
fed-node   Ready     <none>    22h       v1.10.1
```

But when I create a deployment:

```
[root@fed-master ~]# kubectl run hello-world --replicas=2 --labels="run=load-balancer-example" --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0  --port=8080
```

The PODs are not created and are not available:

```
[root@fed-master ~]# kubectl get deployments
NAME          DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello-world   2         0         0            0           21h
```

I noticed that I am missing the kube-system PODs which are available in a Minikube environment, but not on my Fedora Setup:

```
[root@fed-master ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces=true
No resources found.
```

Output of "kubectl describe deploy hello-world":

```
[root@fed-master ~]# kubectl describe deploy hello-world
Name:                   hello-world
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Fri, 01 Jun 2018 22:50:54 +0200
Labels:                 run=load-balancer-example
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision=1
Selector:               run=load-balancer-example
Replicas:               2 desired | 0 updated | 0 total | 0 available | 2 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  run=load-balancer-example
  Containers:
   hello-world:
    Image:        gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    Port:         8080/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type             Status  Reason
  ----             ------  ------
  Available        False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  ReplicaFailure   True    FailedCreate
  Progressing      False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
OldReplicaSets:    <none>
NewReplicaSet:     hello-world-5b446dd74b (0/2 replicas created)
Events:            <none>
```

Output of "kubectl describe pods" is empty:

```
[root@fed-master ~]# kubectl describe pods
[root@fed-master ~]#
```

Output of "systemctl status kube-controller-manager":

```
[root@fed-master kubernetes-cifs-volumedriver]# systemctl status kube-controller-manager 
● kube-controller-manager.service - Kubernetes Controller Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-controller-manager.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-06-04 08:24:47 PDT; 12min ago
     Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
 Main PID: 577 (kube-controller)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 19660)
   Memory: 81.4M
      CPU: 8.568s
   CGroup: /system.slice/kube-controller-manager.service
           └─577 /usr/bin/kube-controller-manager --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=http://fed-master:8080

Jun 04 08:30:26 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: I0604 08:30:26.197657     577 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"DaemonSet", Namespace:"default", Name:"juliohm-cifs-volumedriver-installer", UID:"315149b1-65a4-11e8-8f80-000c29aa0c1d", APIVersion:"apps", ResourceVersion:"17106", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:30:32 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: E0604 08:30:32.195467     577 replica_set.go:450] Sync "default/hello-world-5b446dd74b" failed with No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:30:32 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: I0604 08:30:32.195988     577 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ReplicaSet", Namespace:"default", Name:"hello-world-5b446dd74b", UID:"ce13574b-680b-11e8-826a-000c29aa0c1d", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"18575", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:32:03 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: E0604 08:32:03.143290     577 replica_set.go:450] Sync "default/hello-world-5b446dd74b" failed with No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:32:03 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: I0604 08:32:03.144832     577 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ReplicaSet", Namespace:"default", Name:"hello-world-5b446dd74b", UID:"ce13574b-680b-11e8-826a-000c29aa0c1d", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"18575", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:33:19 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: E0604 08:33:19.074485     577 daemon_controller.go:968] No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:33:19 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: E0604 08:33:19.075327     577 daemon_controller.go:266] default/juliohm-cifs-volumedriver-installer failed with : No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:33:19 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: I0604 08:33:19.076307     577 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"DaemonSet", Namespace:"default", Name:"juliohm-cifs-volumedriver-installer", UID:"315149b1-65a4-11e8-8f80-000c29aa0c1d", APIVersion:"apps", ResourceVersion:"17106", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:34:56 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: E0604 08:34:56.014926     577 replica_set.go:450] Sync "default/hello-world-5b446dd74b" failed with No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
Jun 04 08:34:56 fed-master kube-controller-manager[577]: I0604 08:34:56.015693     577 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ReplicaSet", Namespace:"default", Name:"hello-world-5b446dd74b", UID:"ce13574b-680b-11e8-826a-000c29aa0c1d", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"18575", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account
```

I would appreciate any hint or help!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Try having a look at the `kube-controller-manager` log in your master node. Looks like something critical is not working in your control plane.

Comment: according to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/ the logs should be written here: /var/log - Unfortunately I can not find any kube*.log files in this folder. However the kube-controller-manager process is running and showing up in the process list

Comment: May I ask you how you deployed your cluster?

Comment: I followed the official description: https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config/

Comment: so what does `systemctl status  kube-controller-manager` say?

Comment: I added the output to the issue description.

Comment: You definitely have problems with your cluster `No API token found for service account "default", retry after the token is automatically created and added to the service account`. If this is a test cluster, why don't you use minikube? Otherwise I suggest using kubeadm for the deployment

Comment: In /etc/kubernetes/apiserver the KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL was changed to KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="" according to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/33714

Comment: well, we want to find a production solution and this was my first try. I will check out kubeadm.

Comment: If you are on AWS you could also try kops